# Difference between dying and dead

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> We thought her dead when she slept.
>
> We thought **her dying** when she slept.

I know the second construction is also correct but I don't understand the rule regarding **her dying**(is it a gerund or participle)

Comment: dead is dead, dying is to be in the process of dying. Which are you interested in?

Answer (score 2):

I don't find either one to be very natural. The construction "think [object] [adjective]" is rather literary.

But the meanings are "We thought that she was dead when she slept" and "We thought that she was dying when she slept" - the first seems unlikely, the second somewhat more so.

I suspect that what you are actually intending to say is:

> We thought that she was dying/died/had died in her sleep.

but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

"Dying" in that sentence is a participle. The first sentence means we thought she was dead, and the second sentence means we thought she was dying (not dead yet).